# Error when using https://github.com/Monadical-SAS/minecraft_skin_generator

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, stable-diffusion, diffusers

I tried using this [minecraft skin generator](https://github.com/Monadical-SAS/minecraft_skin_generator) which apparently uses stable diffusion.

I followed the instructions step by step but I got this error:
`RuntimeError: "LayerNormKernelImpl" not implemented for 'Half'`

I downloaded the code from this [minecraft_skin_generator](https://github.com/Monadical-SAS/minecraft_skin_generator). 
I unpacked it and opened a terminal inside it and followed the instructions on that side as well as installing all missing packages including diffusers.

Then I tried to run this example command:
`python bin/minecraft-skins.py output-skin.png "A man in a purple suit wearing a tophat"`
Everything seemed to work fine until I got the error:
`RuntimeError: "LayerNormKernelImpl" not implemented for 'Half'`

I looked it up online and found out that it could be a problem that I am using CPU and no GPU.

Does anyone know how to solve this?